# How to pad a file with "FF" using dd?

Tags: linux, dd, hexadecimal

How to pad a file with `0xFF` using `dd`?

This command will pad the output file with zeroes until the file size reaches 100 KB:

```
dd if=inputFile.bin ibs=1k count=100 of=paddedFile.bin conv=sync
```

However, I want to pad a file with `0xFF`s instead of `0x00`s.

Comment: Note: In my tests (in Debian 12) the command in question does not exactly pad "until the file size reaches 100 KB". I mean that after EOF in `inputFile.bin` (smaller than or equal to 99KiB) my `dd` does *not* add blocks that are full of zeros. Also if `dd` read from something else than a regular file, it could inject zeros somewhere in the middle ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/591952/108618)).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As far as I know you can't tell `dd` to pad a file. But you can tell `dd` to write into a prepadded file.

First create a file of required size filled with `0xFF`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1 count=102400 | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
100+0 records in
200+0 records out
102400 bytes (102 kB) copied, 0,0114595 s, 8,9 MB/s
```

alternatively you can use `head`

```
$ head -c 102400 /dev/zero | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
```

Result:

```
$ hexdump -C paddedFile.bin 
00000000  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00019000
```

Then insert the input file at the beginning of the "padded" file:

```
$ dd if=inputFile.bin of=paddedFile.bin conv=notrunc
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
8 bytes (8 B) copied, 7,4311e-05 s, 108 kB/s
```

Example input file:

```
$ hexdump -C inputFile.bin 
00000000  66 6f 6f 0a 62 61 72 0a                           |foo.bar.|
00000008
```

Result:

```
$ hexdump -C paddedFile.bin 
00000000  66 6f 6f 0a 62 61 72 0a  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |foo.bar.........|
00000010  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00019000
```

---

explanation

```
$ dd if=inputFile.bin of=paddedFile.bin conv=notrunc
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`conv=notrunc` tells `dd` to not truncate the output file.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1 count=102400 | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
                                                          ^^^^^^
```

`tr` expects arguments in octal. `\377` is octal for `0xFF`.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1 count=102400 | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

`tr` can be locale dependent so to be safe set the locale to `C`.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1 count=102400 | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
                  ^^^^^
```

`dd` might write out less bytes if it cannot read one block full of bytes quick enough. to be sure about size you need to set block size of 1. `head` does not have this problem.

read here fore more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278443/whats-the-posix-way-to-read-an-exact-number-of-bytes-from-a-file

Comment: Step 1 works on Linux, but in osx the file `paddedFile.bin` is filled with `c3 bf`. I wonder why? edit: https://superuser.com/questions/1349494/filling-file-with-0xff-gives-c3bf-in-osx

Comment: @Synesso - Yes... and so to provide the initial padded file on macOS, you can do something like `head -c 131072 /dev/zero | LANG=C tr '\000' '\377' > paddedFile.bin`, where 131072 is the required file size.

Comment: FWIW: Enter "hex characters" by `CTRL`+`U` 0022 `Enter` for `"` (hex code 22) or any other Unicode code point. *(Linux, Windows has a similar one, which might need to be enabled though)*

Answer (score 2):

A possible improvement on lesmana's answer is to operate on the file in-place. This could be a lot faster for large input files and will also keep sparse files sparse. However, in many situations you don't want to modify your input file, and so this method will be unsuitable.

The following example starts with a large, sparse input file and pads it up to a size of 1GB with FF chars. Simply change `newsize` to your desired value. As you can see, the `dd` portion takes only a fraction of a second despite this file being very large.

```
$ ls -ld inputFile.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1   …   1073741700   …   inputFile.bin
$ hexdump inputFile.bin
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
3fffff80 0000 0000
3fffff84

$ newsize=$((1024 * 1024 * 1024))
$ filesize=$(stat -c "%s" inputFile.bin)
$ padcount=$((newsize - filesize))
$ dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1 count="$padcount" | tr "\000" "\377" >> inputFile.bin
124+0 records in
0+1 records out
124 bytes (124 B) copied, 0.000162309 s, 764 kB/s

$ ls -ld inputFile.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1   …   1073741824   …   inputFile.bin
$ hexdump inputFile.bin
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
3fffff80 0000 0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
3fffff90 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
*
40000000
```

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: Go to the very last codeblock, just under the bold text that says "This is the full command I would use in my Debian 12".

---

It's possible to do this with a single pipeline.

Concatenate the input file and the output from a source of `0xFF` bytes, then only use `dd` to stop writing to the output file after 100 KiB. This can be done in two ways:

```
# flawed, keep reading
{ cat inputFile.bin && </dev/zero LC_ALL=C tr '\000' '\377'; } | dd ibs=1k count=100 of=paddedFile.bin
```

```
# flawed, keep reading 
</dev/zero LC_ALL=C tr '\000' '\377' | cat inputFile.bin - | dd ibs=1k count=100 of=paddedFile.bin
```

I find the first syntax better because when read from left to right it properly shows data flow:
`inputFile.bin` + what `tr` prints → `paddedFile.bin` of the desired size.
The second syntax starts from `tr`, so it's less elegant in this matter.

Both commands are flawed because [`dd` may read less than `ibs` and still increase the count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121888/108618). The first command will most likely suffer from this, the second command may be lucky and not suffer by chance; still both may suffer. [The only POSIX way to fix this is to use `ibs=1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618):

```
# OK, portable
… | dd ibs=1 count=102400 of=paddedFile.bin
```

where `…` denotes the pre-`dd` fragment of the pipeline from the first or from the second flawed command (both will work fine now, the flaw was from `dd`).

If your `dd` supports `iflag=fullblock` then this will be OK (but not POSIX):

```
# OK, not portable
… | dd ibs=1k count=100 of=paddedFile.bin iflag=fullblock
```

Or if your `head` supports `-c` (also not POSIX) then you can use `head` instead of `dd`:

```
# OK, not portable
… | head -c 102400 > paddedFile.bin
```

Your `head` may even support `-c 100K`. **This is the full command I would use in my Debian 12:**

```
# OK, not portable, quite elegant
{ cat inputFile.bin && </dev/zero LC_ALL=C tr '\000' '\377'; } | head -c 100K > paddedFile.bin
```

Note that any non-flawed command in this answer produces `paddedFile.bin` of the size of exactly 100 KiB (unless a fatal error like `access denied` or so occurs). This is true even if `inputFile.bin` is larger than 100 KiB.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.  I'm using this solution piped to `md5sum` to calculate the checksum to ensure the proper contents of a flash partition (empty bytes are filled with 0xFF).