# Filling file with 0xFF gives C3BF in OSX

Tags: macos, dd

This command will fill the file with `0xff` in Linux.

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=100 | tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
```

When I run it in OSX, the results are different.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=100 | tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
100+0 records in
200+0 records out
102400 bytes transferred in 0.000781 secs (131104008 bytes/sec)
$ hexdump -C paddedFile.bin
00000000  c3 bf c3 bf c3 bf c3 bf  c3 bf c3 bf c3 bf c3 bf  
|................|
*
00032000
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Straight to the point.

It all hinges on the `LANG` or `LC_ALL` value set in your terminal session when you run [`tr`](https://ss64.com/osx/tr.html). Linux has them set to `C` while macOS has it set to something like `en_US.UTF-8`. Of course that `en_US` could be some other local language such as `en_UK` (UK English) but the point is the `[something].UTF-8` setting instead of plain ASCII via `C` is what is causing this.

#### More details.

Seems that [`tr`](https://ss64.com/osx/tr.html) in macOS is converting the `0xff` to the UTF8 equivalent of `c3bf` when it gets instead of the pure ASCII `0xff`. This is explained here on [this Apple community support thread here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4806787?answerId=21246670022#21246670022):

> Linux doesn't handle Unicode in the Terminal like the Mac does. If you set the "LANG" environment variable to "C" (as it probably is on Linux), it will work. Otherwise, all those high-order bits are going to get interpreted as Unicode characters.

And using that `LANG` tip works! Just do the following; tested personally by me just now on macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra).

First, make note of what the existing `LANG` value is like this:

```
echo $LANG
```

The output I see is:

```
en_US.UTF-8
```

Now set the `LANG` value to `C` like this:

```
LANG=C
```

And run that command again:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=100 | tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
```

Now the `hexdump` values should look like this:

```
hexdump -C paddedFile.bin
00000000  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00019000
```

To reset the `LANG` value just close that terminal session or just run this command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Or—as pointed out in the comments—you can just set the `LANG` value straight in the command line options before calling `tr` like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=100 | LANG=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
```

And you can even use `LC_ALL` instead of `LANG` because `LANG` is just derived from `LC_ALL` anyway like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=100 | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377" >paddedFile.bin
```

Comment: "Linux has that set to `C` while macOS has it set to something like `en_US.UTF-8`" -- I'm not sure this is the whole story. In my Kubuntu or Debian `env | grep -E 'LANG|LC'` returns `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8` only, so it's Unicode. Still the OP's original command yields `0xff` out of the box. Could it be because `tr`implementation itself differs between Linux and Mac?

Comment: Regarding my doubt, I have found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165806/108618) which says "many implementations of `tr`, including the one in GNU coreutils, don't support multibyte encodings". Seems legit. In my Debian `tr 'Ł' 'L'` translates `Ł` to `LL` (`Ł` is a Polish letter, I use `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8`), so it apparently treats its first argument as *two* characters.

Comment: Yes, it has to be done by `tr`. It would make negative sense for such conversion to happen when writing to file.

Comment: It's not really hard to test that it's not about the locale setting. With `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (on a Linux system that has that locale generated), `printf ' ' | tr ' ' '\377' | hexdump -C` plainly shows `ff`.

Comment: And, actually, changing `LANG` might not be enough. The relevant locale setting is `LC_CTYPE`, and the value it gets comes first from `LC_ALL`, then `LC_CTYPE`, then `LANG`, with the first one set taking effect (that's the same for all other locale settings). So, if `LC_CTYPE` is set, changing `LANG` doesn't do anything in this case. To reliably override it, you'd need to set `LC_ALL`. Also, it's enough to set it just for `tr`, i.e. `... | LC_ALL=C tr ' ' '\377' | ...`

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that GNU `tr`, which you have on Linux, doesn't really have a concept of multibyte characters, but instead works byte at a time.

The [`tr` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) and online documentation speak of characters, but that's a bit of a simplification. The `TODO` file in the source code package mentions this item (picked from [coreutils 8.30](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.30.tar.xz)):

> Adapt tools like wc, tr, fmt, etc. (most of the textutils) to be
>   multibyte aware.  The problem is that I want to avoid duplicating
>   significant blocks of logic, yet I also want to incur only minimal
>   (preferably 'no') cost when operating in single-byte mode.

On a Linux system—even with a UTF-8 locale (`en_US.UTF-8`)—GNU `tr` replaces an `ä` as two "characters" (the UTF-8 representation of `ä` has two bytes):

```
linux$ echo 'ä' | tr 'ä' 'x'
xx
```

In the same vein, mixing an `ä` and an `ö` produces funny results, since their UTF-8 representations share a common byte:

```
linux$ echo 'ö' | tr ä x
x�
```

Or the other way around (the `x` doesn't apply here):

```
linux$ echo ab | tr ab äx
ä
```

And in your case, GNU `tr` takes the `\377` as a raw byte value.

The `tr` on Mac is different, it knows the concept of multibyte characters and acts accordingly:

```
mac$ echo 'ä' | tr ä x
x

mac$ echo ab | tr ab äx
äx
```

The UTF-8 representation of the character with numerical value 0377 (U+00ff) is the two bytes `c3 bf`, so that's what you get.

The easy way to have `tr` work byte-by-byte is to have it use the C locale, instead of a UTF-8 locale. This gives the funny behavior again:

```
$ echo 'ä' | LC_ALL=C tr 'ä' 'x'
xx
```

And in your case, you can use:

```
... | LC_ALL=C tr "\000" "\377"
```

Or you could use something like Perl to generate those `\xff` bytes:

```
perl -e 'printf "\377" x 1000 for 1..100'
```