# using urandom to generate random strings takes forever

Tags: linux

The time it takes to generate a 10-length string using the following command is acceptable.

```
cat /dev/urandom | strings -n 10 | head -n 1
```

While generating a 255-length string takes forever.

```
cat /dev/urandom | strings -n 255 | head -n 1
```

I have tried it with other length like 30. It’s much longer than it takes with 10. I have compared the consumed time many times. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 1 strings`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings):

> For each file given, GNU `strings` prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.

What are the odds that `strings` encounters 255 *consecutive* printable characters in a random stream? Low, unless you wait long enough.

The below command doesn't require consecutive printable characters in the input stream. It purges non-printable characters.

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc '[:print:]' | head -c 255
```

Note: GNU `tr` works one byte at a time (it has no concept of multibyte characters); then GNU `head -c` counts bytes. Therefore:

- with GNU tools you won't get any printable non-ASCII character (e.g. `Ł`) from the above command;
- with non-GNU implementation of `tr` (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1349765/432690)) you may get less than 255 characters in exactly 255 bytes;
- with non-GNU implementation of `tr` the last character may be invalid; this will happen if `head` cuts the stream in the middle of a multibyte character.

Comment: I thought `strings` filters the printable chars. But instead, it expects a consecutive ones?

Comment: please explain what is `<` in `< /dev/urandom`  as well. :)

Comment: @Tiina It is the same as `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:print:]' | head -c 255`

Comment: @Tiina `<` is a redirection. I avoid [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552). This redirection may or may not be placed at the beginning of the line (explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690)).

Comment: @Tiina - `strings` filters for _strings_ of printable characters, not every individual printable character. The `-n` parameter sets the minimum length for each string and any shorter strings are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a lot of "randomness" quickly, you might consider not using `/dev/urandom` directly, but instead use a plain dm-crypt device with a random key.

It's perfect for overwriting a device, but combining it with a fixed length file you could get a fixed length of random data without waiting for `/dev/urandom` at all.

<sup>(Though your main problem appears to have been waiting for consecutive characters with `strings`, this could still be useful & quicker, solving your "subject line problem")</sup>

Here's the relevant section from [cryptsetup's FAQs](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> ## 2.19 How can I wipe a device with crypto-grade randomness?
>
> The conventional recommendation if you want to not just do a
>   zero-wipe is to use something like
>
> ```
> cat /dev/urandom >  <taget-device>
> ```
>
> ***That is very slow and painful at 10-20MB/s on a fast computer. Using cryptsetup and a plain dm-crypt device with a random key, it is much faster and gives you the same level of security.*** The defaults are quite enough.
>
> For device set-up, do the following:
>
> ```
> cryptsetup open --type plain -d /dev/urandom /dev/<block-device> to_be_wiped
> ```
>
> This maps the container as plain under /dev/mapper/to_be_wiped with a
>   random password.  For the actual wipe you have several options.
>   Simple wipe without progress-indicator:
>
> ```
> cat /dev/zero > /dev/mapper/to_be_wiped
> ```
>
> Progress-indicator by dd_rescue:
>
> dd_rescue -w /dev/zero /dev/mapper/to_be_wiped
>
> Progress-indicator by my "wcs" stream meter (available from
>   http://www.tansi.org/tools/index.html ):
>
> ```
> cat /dev/zero | wcs > /dev/mapper/to_be_wiped
> ```
>
> Or use plain "dd", which gives you the progress when
>   sent a SIGUSR1, see the dd man page.
>
> Remove the mapping at the end and you are done.

---

So creating a fixed length file of say 10M named 10

```
fallocate -l 10M 10
```

Setup the plain dm-crypt on 10, named `/dev/mapper/crypt10`

```
cryptsetup -v open --type plain -d /dev/urandom 10 crypt10
```

Now "overwriting" 10 with crypto-grade randomness (with `dd`) & close the mapping

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/crypt10
cryptsetup -v close crypt10
```

Now you've got 10M of random data in the file 10 to play with, or delete all the non-printable characters using Kamil's answer: "translating" the whole file to the printable file named 10-printable would be

```
tr -dc '[:print:]' < 10  > 10-printable
```

leaving about 3.8M of printable data in 10-printable.